# How can you change signs of the elements of Array in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I just want to ask a question.

I am coding a system of linear equations in two variables using the 2-dimensional array. on the second equation, it is always multiplied with - so that it is easier to solve the x or y in equation 1.

how can you change the sign of the numbers in equation 2 if the ax+by= c is not the same?

I only know how to negate all the numbers in the second equation with the use of negative absolute value but I am facing difficulty if the user inputs on negative and positive numbers in equation 2.(-2x + 3y = -4).

Here is my code (it is not done since I am confused on how to change signs of an array independently because of the user input. I am just a beginner)

```
  /*
   Linear equation using elimination method
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int row = 2;
const int col = 3;
int list[row][col];
int list1[row][col];
int list2[row][col];
int rsize, y, x;
char operation;

int ir, ic;
int *ptr;

//function declaration
void equation1(int list[][col], int rsize);
    //to display the value in 2D array plus linear equation

void Elimination(int list1[][col], int rsize);
    //input the 2 values to elimate in eqn1 and eqn2
    //then display the new equations that is already multiplied to the 2values

void final1(int list1[][col], int rsize,int Y);
    //diplay the value of computed Y and the equation need to substitute the value of Y
    //process and computes the value of X
    //and finally, display the solution set of (x,y)

void final2(int list1[][col], int rsize,int X);
    //diplay the value of computed X and the equation need to substitute the value of X
    //process and computes the value of Y
    //and finally, display the solution set of (x,y)

int deterY(int list2[3]);  //computes the value of Y and returns the value of Y

int deterX(int list2[3]);  //computes the value of X and returns the value of X

char choice();  //display the menu and returns the value of choice


int main() {
    char opt, ulit, operation;
    int equation;
    opt = choice();
    int solve_for_x, solve_for_y;

    switch(opt) {
        case '1':  //two dimensional
            do {
                system("cls");
                cout << "SYSTEMS OF LINEAR EQUATIONS:\n"
                   << "Solving by addition or elimination\n";
             
                //ADD CODE HERE

                cout << "This program uses Addition or Elimination Method.\n"
                     << "We begin by setting up and evaluating the three variables x, y and the constant.\n"
                     << "For example,\n 5x + y = -14 \nshould be entered as 5 1 -14";
                cout << "\n\nPress any key to continue....";
                cin >> opt;
                cin.ignore();                           
                cin.get();    
                system("cls");
       
                cout << "Again, 5x + y = -14 should be entered as 5 1 -14\n";

                //ADD CODE HERE
                equation1(list, row);                     
                cin.ignore();
                cout<<"\n\nPress any key to continue...." <<endl;
                cin.get();
                system("cls");
                Elimination(list1, row);

                cout << "\n\n\n";
                cout << "What variable do you want to change: \n";
                cout << "x or y\n"; 
                cin >> operation;
                switch(operation){      
                    case 'x':
                        solve_for_x = deterX(list2[3]);
                        cout << solve_for_x <<endl;
                        break;
                    case 'y':
                        solve_for_y = deterY(list2[3]);
                        cout << solve_for_y << endl;
                        break; 
                }
                //Call function Elimination here
               
                //ADD CODE HERE
                     
                   
            } while (toupper(ulit) == 'Y');
            break;
        case '2': 
            //ADD CODE HERE
            break;
    } //end switch
  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}  //end main

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char choice() {
    cout << "<<<<<<<MENU>>>>>>>" << endl;
    cout <<"[1] Systems of Linear Equation"<<endl;
    cout <<"[2] Quit" << endl;
    cout <<"Enter your choice:" << endl;
    
    char opt;
    cin >> opt;
     
    return opt;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void equation1(int ist[][col], int rsize) {
    cout << "Enter Equation 1:";
    for(ir = 0; ir < row; ir++) {
        for(ic = 0; ic < col; ic++) {
            if(ir == 0 && ic >= 0) {
                cin >> list[ir][ic];
            }
            if(ir == 1 && ic >= 0) {
                cout << "Enter Equation 2:";
                cin >> list[ir][ic];
            }
        }
    }
} //end equation1

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Elimination(int list1[][col], int rsize) {
    cout << "you have entered (using 2-dimensional array)" << endl;
    for(ir = 0; ir < row; ir++) {
        for(ic = 0; ic < col; ic++) {
            cout < <setw(7) << list[ir][ic];
        }
        cout << endl;       
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "SOLVING SIMPLE EQUATIONS" << endl;
    cout << setw(7) << list[0][0] << "x" << " + " <<list[0][1] << "y" << " = " << list[0][2] << endl;
    cout << setw(7) << list[1][0] << "x" << " + " <<list[1][1] << "y" << " = " << list[1][2] << endl;
    
    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    cout <<"_____________________________________________________ "<< endl;
    cout << "Please enter the value to eliminate the variable" << endl;
    cout << "for example... if you have:" <<endl;
    cout << "2x + 3y = 10" << endl;
    cout << "4x + 5y = 15" << endl;
    cout << "if you want to eliminate the x.. you need to input -2" << endl;
    cout << "(for 2x to become -4x in eqn.1) and 1 (to remain the value in eqn.2" << endl;
    cout << "if you want to eliminate y.. you need to input -/+5 in eqn1 and +-3 in eqn.2" << endl;
    cout << "enter the value for equation 1: 1 " << endl;
    cout << "enter value for equation 2: -1 " << endl;
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << "ELIMINATING EQUATIONS" << endl;
    
    cout << setw(7) << list[0][0] <<"x" << " + " <<list[0][1] <<"y" << " = " << list[0][2] << endl;
    cout << setw(7) << -abs(list[1][0])<<"x" << " + " << -abs(list[1][1]) <<"y" <<  " = " << -abs(list[1][2]) << endl;

    cout <<"===================================================== "<< endl;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int deterY(int list2[3]){}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
int deterX(int list2[3]) {}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void final1(int list1[][col], int rsize,int Y) {}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void final2(int list1[][col], int rsize,int X) {}
```

Comment: Multiply by `-1`?

Comment: i cant explain it properly but its like -(2x +3y = 16) so that x or y can be easily cancelled

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is your problem? Show us your whole code, please.

Comment: i am just trying to know how to change the signs of the elements of an array since it is user-dependent

Comment: @user12911595 - What's the issue with simply multiplying all the coefficients by `-1`?

Comment: if the user inputs negative and positive numbers how will my program know if it changes the sign of a number? for example if the user input positive number it will output a negative number since it is multiplied by -1 but if the user inputs a negative number the output of it should be positive since - * - =+

Comment: Look at the words of the question you posted.  To automatically turn a negative number to positive, or a positive number to negative, a multiplication of `-1` to that number can be done.  So what really are you asking for?  From your further comments, it seems to be much more than just toggling the sign of a number, unless you never realized that multiplying a number by `-1` flips the sign.

Comment: _"... like -(2x +3y = 16) ..."_ - you mean `-2x - 3y = -16` (or, more usually, `-2x - 3y + 16 = 0`)? Because that's multiplying  all the coefficients by `-1`.

Comment: oh wait my apologies i get it now it only needs to be multiplied by one I thought there is like a complicated loop to add! sorry sorry this project is deadline on 2 hrs lol. Thank you for your help! hope I can finish it